# Using Cesium with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, cesiumjs

Cesium is a big library, and (1.16+) can be installed via NPM.

However, due to the nature of the library, there is no index.js, uses requirejs (and so presumably AMD modules) but I'm yet to find a way to `require` it for use with Webpack.

There are a number of ways to get around this, but all of them require moving files from the /node_modules/ folder to a statically served directory. This includes moving the prebuilt files, and the source files ([like this example shows](https://github.com/mmacaula/cesium-webpack/)).

I understand that Cesium is working on rewriting their modules to be ES6 compatible, but with the size of the library, there hasn't been a lot of progress in this regard.

Is there a way to configure Webpack to cope with the complexity of Cesium? Ideally we could use it in-situ during development, and then add the required files to a bundle for production.